# Drupal chat as help desk module for visitors

Tags: drupal, chat

I'm trying to use this chat system for Drupal to help my visitors.
https://drupal.org/project/drupalchat

I could manage to show it to visitors, but the problem is that visitors can see a list of all people on the chat including other visitors. I need they only see administrators to get help from. Also the title of the chat box is "chat", do you know how can I change it to something like :" support". As last question, do you know any alternative solution that be free? I saw one with voice and video!! But I couldn't find any free one.

Comment: maybe what you need is not a chat module, but a support module.

Comment: Well yes, but is there any out there that be free and I can host it? Also that support called system also should have chat function, doesn't it?

Comment: facebook has a chat and is not a support system. I hope you understand my point here, a good and clear question will increase your chances for getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

DrupalChat module (https://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) now provides this functionality. You may use free plan of its cloud based commercial version in order to access this feature. Thanks.